# Jenkins Git SCM Polling stops when the job for which polling is happening is running

Tags: jenkins, polling

We have a job in a jenkins environment which is triggered based on the changes found in the git source code repository.

When the job is running, the git polling log shows nothing and until the job finishes the execution, polling log doesn't have anything on it.

It always shows log after completing the job and another note is that, enable concurrent builds option is not set to make sure only one build runs at a time.

I would like to understand whether it is a known behavior on jenkins front to halt polling when the job is running and whether the concurrent builds option is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and discovered this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7423

It looks like it's related to the polls requiring a workspace in order to perform the checkout. You can manually kick off new builds and they will pick up SCM changes.